# Excel/Word on MAC - includepicture containing url

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, mail-merge

I have the following:
A excel spreadsheet with names and url's to a QR code, each in a column of the spreadsheet. The url returns a jpeg picture of the QR code.
A word doc where these names and pictures should merge into, and then printed as badges.
It works on Windows and now trying to do the same on a MAC with Office for MAC.

This is my field code in word: `{INCLUDEPICTURE"{MERGEFIELD url}"}
"url" is a column in the excel spreadsheet.

It works when picture / qr code is a local file on the harddrive, but when I try to get it from the web by inserting the url it does not get the picture or insert a picture.

This is the instruction I followed to get it to work on windows - http://beyondthekeeboard.wordpress.com/2009/09/18/creating-a-mail-merge-in-word-using-qr-codes-from-google-maps-api/

Any ideas or suggestions??

Comment: Have you tried removing the MERGEFIELD and inserting the URL in directly to test? Make sure to press F9 to update the field.